# Mockito .thenReturn(list.add()) actually adds something to my list

Tags: java, list, mocking, mockito

I am trying to test one of my functions, which adds something to a database if a condition is true.
Now in my test class I am trying to mock this on a list:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
String myString  = "";

when(xxx.addToDatabase()).thenReturn(list.add(myString));
```

So if my condition is true this assertion should be correct:

```
AssertTrue(list.contains(Object)).
```

And if my condition is false this assertion should apply:

```
AssertFalse(list.contains(Object));
```

So my problem is, that the my list always contains the Object, since the `.thenReturn` seems to be called even if it's not actually called.

Is there a way to prevent the `list.add()` being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
when(xxx.addToDatabase()).thenReturn(list.add(myString));
```

... is invoked in your *test* regardless of whether `xxx.addToDatabase()` is invoked in the *code under test*.

So, you are adding `myString` to `list` in your test case. This explains the following:

> my list always contains the Object

Re this:

> Is there a way to prevent the list.add() being called?

I think there might be some misunderstanding of how to use a mock here.

The following line ...

```
when(xxx.addToDatabase()).thenReturn(list.add(myString));
```

... means: when `xxx.addToDatabase()` is invoked then return `true` since `list.add()` returns a boolean. I suspect that what you want to happen is to perform `list.add` as a *side effect* of `xxx.addToDatabase()`. If so, then you may want to use `doAnswer` instead of `doReturn`. If you update your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be easier to guide you.

Comment: ye, but how can i prevent this and still forward my actual call to my list.add() ?

Comment: @Asiemie see the updated answer. If you could add your test case (or at least a cut down version of it which clearly replicates your issue) then it should be fairly simple to provide you with an answer to the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am pretty new to Mockito and SO also pretty bad in asking questions. With .doAnswer it seems to work now. Thank you very much!

Comment: "I am pretty new to Mockito and SO also pretty bad in asking questions." ... don't be so hard on yourself :) aside from the lack of formatting the question looked ok to me.

Comment: Thanks again for your great help and nice words. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be doing.

```
List<> someList = new ArrayList();
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    someList.add(myString);
     // return something
    }).when(xxx).addToDatabase();
```